# Creating outlook appointment with html body using webdav

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, webdav

I'm creating outlook appointments using webdav. I'm using following post body to create the appointment.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<g:propertyupdate xmlns:g="DAV:" 
    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/"
    xmlns:mapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/"
    xmlns:mapit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
    xmlns:x="xml:"
    xmlns:cal="urn:schemas:calendar:"
    xmlns:dt="urn:uuid:c2f41010-65b3-11d1-a29f-00aa00c14882/"
    xmlns:colors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/"
    xmlns:header="urn:schemas:mailheader:"
    xmlns:mail="urn:schemas:httpmail:"
>
<g:set>
<g:prop>
<g:contentclass>urn:content-classes:appointment</g:contentclass>
    <e:outlookmessageclass>IPM.Appointment</e:outlookmessageclass>
    <mail:subject>Test</mail:subject>
    <mail:htmldescription>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN&quot;&quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
            &lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;
            &lt;table&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Telefonnummer:&lt;/td&gt;
                    &lt;td&gt;&lt;b&gt;123123423453245&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name&lt;/td&gt;
                    &lt;td style=&quot;color:red;&quot;&gt;Hille, Christian&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;
            &lt;/body&gt;
            &lt;/html&gt;
    </mail:htmldescription>
    <cal:location></cal:location>
    <cal:dtstart dt:dt="dateTime.tz">2009-10-05T14:37:17.000Z</cal:dtstart>
    <cal:dtend dt:dt="dateTime.tz">2009-10-05T14:52:17.000Z</cal:dtend>
    <cal:busystatus>BUSY</cal:busystatus>
    <cal:reminderoffset dt:dt="int">900</cal:reminderoffset>
    <colors:0x8214 dt:dt="int">10</colors:0x8214>
    </g:prop>
</g:set>
</g:propertyupdate>
```

The appointment is created. But outlook does not display the text as formated in html. The bold text is formated bold. The table and the style attribute are ignored.

Does outlook support html body formating? How to display the table in appointment body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some research.

There is **no support** to full html formating using webdav. Some basic html tags are supported (`<b>`, `<i>`) but tables are not.

Advanced formating is only possible using rtf formating.
**BUT** rtf formated appointments are not accessible through webdav. You will get a http 502 error doing this.

Read more:
http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=6599
http://blogs.msdn.com/deva/archive/2008/07/16/kb-application-support-for-webdav-to-access-exchange-server.aspx